# Is it possible to query serial port tx pin status (signal low / high) in windows?

Tags: windows, serial-port, uart

Is it possible to query serial port tx (send) pin status if it is active or not ?

For example when issuin break command (SetCommBreak) tx pin is set to active (low). I'd like to know when it is active or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  (at least not likely)

If you are using the "16550" family of UARTs, then I am confident that you can not query the serial port tx pin status.  Of course, if you are using some new version or other UART family, maybe.

You can *assume* that the TX pin is in the SPACE state ('0', +Volts) whilst performing `SetCommBreak()`, but I suspect that is not enough for you.

---

If you are look to debug your code to *know* if a break occurred, you can short pins 2 & 3 on a 9-pin D-sub, thus loop backing the transmit to the receive.  A paper clip will do.  Your receive code would detect the incoming BREAK.  Shorting to the incorrect pin does not cause a lasting problem with a conforming serial port, but be careful.  Try this first with simple data, before testing BREAK condition.

---

If you have a "16550"-like UART.

You can put the UART into loop-back mode and see if you receiving you own outgoing  BREAK signal.  Its somewhat complicated in current PCs.  Other UART type may support loop-back.

Comment: thanks for a very good answer. Yes, I do have normal PC with 16550 UART. I was wondering how for example realterm program knows how to turn on TX and RX pin status. But now I know it has to be done in the program. It works probably something like this: during read turn RX indicator, and TX on write. It can also detect 'break condition' or 'SPACE state'.

Comment: *"you can short pins ... thus loop backing"*  -- Umm, the verb you're looking for is "looping back".  "*Shorting to the incorrect pin does not cause a lasting problem"* -- That's a requirement for EIA/RS232 transceiver driver chips, but not logic-level UART/USART devices.  BTW - most all UART/USART detect and then report a Break condition in the Status register.  Oftentimes a change in this Status register (e.g. a Break has been detected or modem control signal changed) is configured/used to generate an interrupt.